# Problem connecting to BLE ( RN4080 Microchip based) device with Android 8.1.0

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have developed an app which connects to  BLE device ( based on RN4080 Microchip board). Connection to device is successful and works as expected. For a specific phone based on 8.1 the connection happens but onConnectionStateChange callback is called with newState as BluetoothProfile#STATE_DISCONNECTED

App works with various other phones, but fails only on specific phone ( ASUS Zenfone Max M1, with Android 8.1)
Another observation is when phone is restarted , the app works fine, but stops working after some usage. Unfortunately I am not able to figure out what actions makes the app fail.

Any clue or direction will help to resolve the issue?

Comment: With BLE, I always face some problems on ASUS series devices , and it need to restart as always.

Comment: So what does logcat say? Are the gatt if instances leaking?

Comment: logcat does not show any errors / leaks..